# Optimizing SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

As an assignment I need to clean up a movie database.

Some users has been deleted, and i have to remove ratings from users no longer in the database.

I made this query

```
DELETE rating FROM rating LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM user) as A ON A.id = rating.userId WHERE A.id IS NULL;
```

I've made indexes on rating.userId and user.Id

As there is 6000 users and 1.000.000 ratings, this takes insanely long time. Can anyone figure out how i can perform this, or a query like this, with better performance?

Comment: `A.id = rating.userId WHERE A.id IS NULL` isn't that equivalent to `rating.userId = NULL`?

Comment: @njzk2 not necessarily, I suspect this code is to delete data from rating where the user no longer exists.  If the database had referential integrity configured, OP probably wouldn't have to write this.

Comment: Can you quantify "Insanely long time"?

Comment: Insanely long time is not completing within 30mins. It completed in 23 secs with @juergen-d is answer :)

Comment: shouldn't you use sonmething like on delete cascade?

Comment: I probably should, but it's not something that the course is covering - I didn't know on delete cascade and just read up on it, it seems pretty cool :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the unnecessary subselect

```
DELETE rating 
FROM rating 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = rating.userId 
WHERE user.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this `SELECT` query and confirm that these are the rows you want to delete.

```
SELECT * FROM rating WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM user);
```

If they match you can simply run a query like this.

```
DELETE FROM rating WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM user);
```